# SonarLint low performance on network share

Tags: performance, networking, share, sonarlint

When the sonarlint analsysis is done over the network the performance is very bad.
I have local Eclipse installation, where I do SonarLint analysis. There the performance is good. When the same analysis is done where Eclipse starts from network share and the Eclipse Workspace is also on a network share the performance is 20 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

A SonarLint analysis does a lot of I/O, so that's expected.

Nevertheless, performance is constantly being improved so hopefully you'll experience better analysis times with future versions.